# About image augmentation in tensorflow training

Tags: tensorflow, data-augmentation, image-classification

I am doing an image classification problem. I would like to have image augmentation like resizing, flip, cutout, random contrast etc
I am wondering if I should augment the images first and save them to tfrecords for use, or I should just create a tfrecord of the original images and do the augmentation during training?
Does it make a huge computational resource difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can see in this example, you can add whatever you want in the pipeline.config of the model you use. As an example, this part can be added to the config of the ssd_mobile_net.

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 64
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_vertical_flip{
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_rotation90{
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_pad_image{
    }
  }
```

To visualize what each option is doing with your pics, you can use this code.
[Visualize_Augmentation](https://github.com/MostafaFiroozi/visualize_augmentation)